# How to find source formula of brew package (github repo)?

Tags: macos, homebrew, git

How can I find the sources and changes for a given `brew` package?

I'm having an issue with a package that's installed via `brew` on a cloud instance whose image I don't control. I'm trying to figure out if the issue is a result of the package installed from `brew` or not.

I want to find the source for that package in the brew system (that is, the git or other VCS where the formula/cask are maintained) and see what changes were made to the package in the past few days/weeks, look through the commits, and read their `CHANGELOG`.

How can I determine the repository for a given package on `brew` and look through its commits over time?

Answer (score 1):

If your package is in homebrew-core, then you can view the recipe's ruby source and its changes from the `homebrew-core` repo in the `Formula` directory

- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/tree/master/Formula

Unfortunately, finding the recipe for a given `brew` package on github.com may be tricky, since there's too many dirs and GitHub may truncate or refuse the output.

Instead, you can get and list all the homebrew forumulas with the following commands in `zsh`:

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git
cd homebrew-core/Formula
find . | grep -i <package>
```

Then you can show the history of a given formula with `git log`

For example, I was able to discover that the `python@3.7` package in `brew` changed yesterday:

```
user@host ~ % git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core.git
Cloning into 'homebrew-core'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 77, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (77/77), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
remote: Total 791472 (delta 51), reused 59 (delta 43), pack-reused 791395
Receiving objects: 100% (791472/791472), 316.25 MiB | 9.55 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (529456/529456), done.
Updating files: 100% (5476/5476), done.
user@host ~ % cd homebrew-core/Formula
user@host Formula %

user@host Formula % find . | grep -i python
./python-yq.rb
./boost-python.rb
./python-markdown.rb
./app-engine-python.rb   
./ipython.rb
./python@3.7.rb
./gst-python.rb
./micropython.rb
./wxpython.rb
./reorder-python-imports.rb
./python@3.8.rb
./boost-python3.rb
user@host ~ %

user@host Formula % git log master -n1 python@3.7.rb
commit 10d3df6c9a263c4e7dea4752a00a1b98ddc9c05a
Author: BrewTestBot <1589480+BrewTestBot@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Wed Sep 9 00:40:17 2020 +0000

    python@3.7: update 3.7.9 bottle.
user@host Formula %
```